# $L^2$ of a fiber bundle

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, fiber-bundles

For spaces $X$ and $Y$ with measures there is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces 
$$L^2(X) \otimes L^2(Y) \to L^2(X\times Y), ~~ f\otimes g\mapsto \left((x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)\right).$$

Now suppose $E \to X$ is a (locally trivial) fiber bundle with fiber $F$.  Is there any nice relationship between $L^2(E)$ adn $L^2(F)\otimes L^2(X)$?